# Script to look for specific folder names, then copy contents to destination path

Tags: windows, vbscript, powershell-3.0

I'm looking for some help with finding a script, or getting a starting point, as i'm a bit new to scripting. Basically what i'm trying to achieve is the following.

A specific folder name, lets call it "folder1" is a subfolder in a directory "dir1". I am trying to have a script find all instances of "folder1" in the "dir1" and copy all of those contents with the folder structure intact if possible, to a location on a different drive.

I have looked through ROBOCOPY and XCOPY and it doesn't seem like either of those can help. Any resources, samples, or recommendations would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

xCopy did it for me:

```
xCopy "E:\tempNet\x" "E:\tempNet\z" /E /Q /H /K /O /X /B /Y /R /G /C /I /V
```

- /E           Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.
- /Q           Does not display file names while copying.
- /H           Copies hidden and system files also.
- /K           Copies attributes. Normal Xcopy will reset read-only attributes.
- /O           Copies file ownership and ACL information.
- /X           Copies file audit settings (implies /O).
- /B           Copies the Symbolic Link itself versus the target of the link.
- /Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.
- /R           Overwrites read-only files.
- /G           Allows the copying of encrypted files to destination that does not support encryption.
- /C           Continues copying even if errors occur.
- /I           If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.
- /V           Verifies the size of each new file.

Type "**xcopy /?**" for all details, and run as Admin